# Autocomplete jQuery Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, autocomplete, show

here is my problem:

I got an HTML table with a scheme like:

```
Group 1
  Content 1
  Content 2
  Content 3
Group 2
  Content 4
  Content 5
etc..
```

Now, with **CSS** i ***hided*** the sub-rows corresponding to each group like:

```
.content1, .content2, etc... {
display: none;
}
```

Everything seems pretty easy, when the user clicks on a group, the respective rows are shown through jQuery `fadeIn()` method.

But then, **WHY** `autocomplete method` related to inputs in sub-rows is showing in the proper way only without the css declaration `display:none` ?

I will post two images: the first one is without the `display:none` property, the second one got the property and the `fadeIn ()` me!thod has already been called.!

[Without css property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzd3u.jpg)

[With css property and fadeIn invoked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOddd.jpg)

***Note: I want autocomplete to show after fadeIn() invocation properly.***

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setup a width 100% for the tag that has autocomplete on it?

Comment: yep ! lets say i got my field which class id "text", well in css i tried .text {width:100%}; I'm sure 100% that the problem is caused by the display:none property

Comment: can you provide code so we can help you?

Comment: Well, it is very long and complex, but if you want to try, take a blank document,create 1 input and set its style to display:none, write down a jQuery autocomplete function to that input, make the input appear through fadeIn() method and see that it is not working properly.

Comment: what if u use hide().fadeIn() instead display:none;, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655333/fadein-appendto-with-ui-item-value